# How to list the available tables in different keyspaces in Amazon Keyspaces/Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, cql, amazon-keyspaces

I am trying to implement an application using AWS Keyspace Cassandra and Cassandra Python driver. I had created 3 keyspaces in my AWS console.

I am trying to find if there is any query which can list down all the available tables in all 3 keyspaces in one go.
I tried below query but it's failing.

```
SELECT table_name, keyspace_name from system_schema.tables where keyspace_name IN ('mykeyspace','cycling')
```

Does CQL editor in AWS Keyspace not allow use of IN keyword? Anybody knows such a query or command?

Comment: The above query works for me, I tried on cqlsh .

Comment: Above query will work.

Comment: I checked it also. And it works in Cassandra but it's not supported in AWS Keyspaces yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below query works in Cassandra to list the available tables in different keyspaces.

```
SELECT table_name, keyspace_name from system_schema.tables where keyspace_name IN ('mykeyspace','cycling');
```

But it fails for AWS Keyspaces as **IN** keyword is not supported in AWS Keyspaces yet.

Answer (score 2):

It does allow us to use IN clause in Cassandra and even I am able to access the tables with the same query.

cassandra@cqlsh> SELECT table_name, keyspace_name from system_schema.tables where  keyspace_name in ('system_traces','youkudbhelper');

table_name             | keyspace_name
------------------------+---------------

(10 rows)
cassandra@cqlsh> exit
bash-4.2$ cqlsh --version
cqlsh 5.0.1
bash-4.2$

## References:

https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql-oss/3.3/cql/cql_using/useQueryIN.html

Comment: I checked it also. And it works in Cassandra but it's not supported in AWS Keyspaces yet.